# CakePHP: on login, redirecting to last page viewed before logout

Tags: php, cakephp

I've implemented Authentication and Authorization in Cake, and mostly it works as needed.
However, if I hit log out from a page that requires particular credentials (say /admin) and log back in as another differently privileged user, I get redirected to /admin and an error message displayed.

Looking at the request headers in chrome, I notice that the Cookie CAKEPHP is still set even after log out.

```
public function login() {
    ...
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
              $this->set('login_failed', false);
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
    ...
    }
}


public function logout() {
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Any ideas about how I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign this to your AppController

```
public $components = array(               
        'Auth'=> array(                
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action'=>'login'),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
          )
)
```

your logout function also is incorrect. You should do this:

```
public function logout(){
       $this->Auth->logout();                
       $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginAction);
}
```

[loginRedirect](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent%3a%3aredirectUrl)

[logoutRedirect](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent%3a%3a%24logoutRedirect)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Could you tell me what that does exactly. Even without that, after logging out I'm redirected to the correct page, so  redirection is clearly not the only thing it does.

Also, when logging in the first time, I'm shown the AuthError message. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm don't quite understand what loginAction, loginRedirect and logoutAction are for exactly either.

Comment: I have attached more info it is not bad to read the Auth component to see how Auth behaviours works :). hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of cake you are using, but you can try to unset the cookie and that should keep it from going to the last viewed page. You can add it to logout or to beforefilter().

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the CakePHP version.

But you could try:

`$this->Session->delete('Auth.redirect');`

Which is working on CakePHP 2.x

Comment: I'd prefer if the entire session was destroyed on log out though... I  assumed that that'd be the default behaviour

Comment: `Auth.redirect` should be cleared from the session after logging out, but it will remain in session when trying to access a page which requires authentication and redirects you to login page. Maybe your `$Auth->logoutRedirect` is incorrect?

Comment: Thanks that worked, I've commented on Isaac's answer

Answer (score 0):

Is admin a prefix? If so, try setting admin to false for the logout link in the admin view.