# HOw to Prevent to access visited page after logout in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Please answer my question. I do not get satisfactory answer.

Question is : "How to Prevent to access visited page after logout in cakephp?"
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598245/cakephp-on-login-redirecting-to-last-page-viewed-before-logout) relevant?

Answer (score 0):

In the AppController **beforeFilter**:

```
// Check if the user is logged in
if (isset($this->Auth->user())) {
    // Save the visited page in session
    $this->Session->write('VisitedPages.', $this->here());
// If the user is not logged in
} else {
    // If the user has logged out and visited the page before
    if (isset($this->Session->read('VisitedPages.'.$this->here()))) {
        $this->redirect('/errorPage');
    }
}
```